# linux sed syntax

Tags: linux, sed

I am trying to delete this string

```
;document.write('<iframe src="http://google.com" scrolling="auto" frameborder="no" align="center" height="11" width="11"></iframe>');
```

across all files within a directory (sub directories included).

I know I have to escape characters or use regex. However I am awful with regex. Any insight appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use regex if you want to delete a fixed string. You can put it in a sed command as is, but choose a separator other than any characters in the string (I use `#` here):

```
str=";document.write('<iframe src="'"http://google.com" scrolling="auto" frameborder="no" align="center" height="11" width="11"></iframe>'"');"
find . -type f -exec sed -i.bk -e "s#$str##g" {} \;
```

Comment: I tried using the above str variable declaration, but I get "an unexpected token <". I then try to escape those characters and fall into further error. This was the same circle I was in before. Any ideas. thanks for the help.

Comment: @ChadCaldwell Did you escape the single quotes? I edited to add this.

Comment: Yes. When I run just the first line from above I get this error:
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
I then escape that and get the newline ">" in bash, I believe that means an unterminated script

Comment: @ChadCaldwell You're right. It's easier to switch quotes as needed, I've made another edit.